# Styling polymer - once for all browsers

Tags: html, css, polymer

How can I style polymer once for all browsers ?
Now I have to write two css versions for Chrome/Opera and Firefox:

```
.leftSide img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
content[select=".poster"]::content img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Html:

```
        <div class="leftSide">
                <content select=".poster"></content>
        </div>
```

This works only on new Opera and Chrome:

```
content[select=".poster"]::content img
```

This works only on firefox:

```
.leftSide img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

So, is there any option to write code once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `polyfill-next-selector`? [Documentation for it here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html)

With that you should be able to do:

```css
polyfill-next-selector {content: ':host .leftSide img';}
content[select=".poster"]::content img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```